# return value from function after casper method

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

In the code below I want to call `checkMainBox(cthis)`. I want to set it up so that this function will either return the number retrieved or false. But in `checkMainBox()` I don't know how to return a value. number is returned undefined. I'm pretty sure I can't to do it this way because of asynchronous behavior but what is the next best way?

```
function checkMainBox(cthis){
    var number;
    cthis.waitForSelector("._XWk", function(){
        cthis.capture("result.png");
        cthis.then(function(){
            var number = cthis.evaluate(function(){
                return $("._XWk").txt();
            })

            // console.log("number", number);
        })
    })
    return number
}

function getPhoneNumber(cthis){
    console.log("NUMBER::", checkMainBox(cthis));
       //checkMainBox(cthis) should return false or the number
}

casper.on("error", function(msg){
    this.echo("error: " + msg, "Error");
})
casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace){
    this.echo("Page Error: " + msg, "error");
});
casper.on("remote.message", function(message){
    this.echo("Remote: " + message);
});

casper.start("http://google.com/", function(){
    this.waitForSelector("form[action='/search']");
});
casper.then(function(){
    this.fill("form[action='/search']", {q : "ebay.com phone number"}, true);
})
casper.then(function(){
    getPhoneNumber(this)
})
casper.run();
```

EDIT::

recent attempt with promise but if you have another way to do it feel free to share it:

```
function checkMainBox(cthis){
    var number;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        cthis.waitForSelector("._XWk", function(){
            cthis.capture("result.png");
            cthis.then(function(){
                var number = cthis.evaluate(function(){
                    return $("._XWk").txt();
                })

                resolve(number)
            })
        });
    })

}

function getPhoneNumber(cthis){
    checkMainBox(cthis).then(function(result){
        console.log("NUMBER::", checkMainBox(result));
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        if(err) console.log(err);
    })

}
```

ERROR : `error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Promise`

EDIT 2 :

```
function getPhoneNumber(cthis){
    // var number;
    cthis.waitForSelector("._XWk", function(){
        cthis.capture("result.png");
        cthis.then(function(){
            var number = cthis.evaluate(function(){
                return $("._XWk").html();
            })
            checkMainBox(number);
            // console.log("number", number);
        })
    })
}

function checkMainBox (number){
    // console.log("NUMBER::", number);
    return number
}
```

...

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.fill("form[action='/search']", {q : "ebay.com phone number"}, true);
})
casper.then(function(){
    var number;
    console.log(getPhoneNumber(this)) // should be the value

})
casper.run();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: It looks like you should make `checkMainBox` return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: I still need help restructuring it for this case after reading the top answer.I would like to continue the casper.then() chain in the main part of the code.

Comment: can you please show me how? I know about promise. I should make the whole `cthis.waitForSelector` into a promise and then return it?

Comment: I tried it : `error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Promise`

Comment: If promises aren't available, you can give `checkMainBox` a callback function as a parameter, and call it when the value is available. The dupe question shows how to do that.

Comment: I did something like what you suggested but I would still like the `number` value in the main `casper.then()` thread. is it possible? see second edit.

Comment: @jackblank `casper.wait(4000).then(function(){getPhoneNumber(this) })` because `casper.then(function(){` will be executed instantly, after submitting a form.

Comment: @jackblank as it going?

Comment: If the given answer solved your problem, you may [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/266187) it. If it didn't, then please expand on what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a poor man's Promise (important stuff is bold):

```
function checkMainBox(cthis){
    var number = {};
    cthis.waitForSelector("._XWk", function(){
        cthis.capture("result.png");
        cthis.then(function(){
            number.value = cthis.evaluate(function(){
                return $("._XWk").txt();
            })
        })
    })
    return number
}

function getPhoneNumber(cthis){
    var number = checkMainBox(cthis));
    cthis.then(function(){
        console.log("outer: " + number.value);
    });
}
```

CasperJS already provides an environment that is similar to Promises, but you still have to have an empty object that can receive the value asynchronously. The `cthis.then` is important because it handles the waiting until the `cthis.waitForSelector` inside of `checkMainBox` is finished.